# PostgreSQL problema de conexão

Tags: postgresql

Meu PostgreSQl recém instalado deu esse erro:

> could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is
>   the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP
>   connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection
>   refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost"
>   (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Alguém uma solução?

Comment: Esse erro é no seu pc? o serviço está ativo? o pc onde o postgres está instalado é o mesmo onde vc tentou acessar?

Comment: como faço para saber se o serviço está rodando?

Comment: É windows ou linux?

Comment: realmente o serviço não estava ativo, muito obrigado, o meu é Windows.